# Django ImageField/FileField save uploaded file using model's pk

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload, pim

I'm converting a legacy site (originally written in rails) and by default the images were saved using the format `{{pk}}.{{extension}}` and that file was always overwritten if a new file is uploaded.
I'd like to continue that format with this django version.

I originally thought extending FileSystemStorage would be te way to go, but I don't know of a way to pass the current model object to it. Anyone have a suggestion on a "django way" to accomplish this?

If I need to write my own class that extends `ImageField` to manage this, then so be it. :) Just wondering if there was something simple I'm missing.

[edit] *WHAT I DID, BASED ON ANSWER FROM **surfeurx** and **DrTyrsa***:

```
temp_image = None

def image_path(self, uploaded_file_name):
    prefix = 'designs/'
    extension = os.path.splitext(uploaded_file_name)[-1]
    if self.pk != None:
        return prefix + str(self.pk) + extension
    else:
        tmp_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.temp_image = prefix + tmp_name + extension
        return self.temp_image

image_upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, null=True, blank=True) 

def save(self):
    self.updated_at = datetime.now()

    is_new = self.pk == None
    super(Design, self).save()

    if is_new:
        if self.temp_image != None:
            os.rename(MEDIA_ROOT + self.temp_image, MEDIA_ROOT + self.image_path(self.temp_image))
            self.temp_image = None
```

The real problem I'm having now is that I want it to overwrite the image. This will provide the right file name, but it looks like I'm going to have to extend `ImageField` to get it to overwrite. Found this little guy: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/636/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use upload_to like:

```
def image_path(instance, filename):
    return instance.id + os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

class Brand(models.Model):
    ...
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. Although I feel dirty. This seems like the least elegant thing I've ever had to write in django.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) function. It accepts `instance` as an argument. But don't forget that if you are *creating* the instance it won't have `pk` yet (but you can save it first, and then save the image).